# Javascript/Jquery : get document referrer, when clicked browser's back button

Tags: javascript, referrer

Situation:

I have **page1.html**, on which i need to get document referrer

For example, i go to **page0.html**, then go to **page1.html**

On **page1.html** there are list of subpages

I click on some of them and go to **page1_sub1.html**

Then i click browser's back button and go to **page1.html**

On **page1.html** i need to get referrer (**page1_sub1.html**)
but document.referrer actually shows as **page0.html**

So, is it possible to get document referrer if clicked back button of browser or user go back via referrence like

```
<a href="javascript:history.back();">« Back</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, that won't work. If needed, you can use cookies to store the history of pages users have opened—but that's complicated, and will fail if the user has your site open in different tabs.